# Как плавно убрать задний фон при нажатии?

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, css-animation

Сделал смену заднего фона через keyframe с opacity от 0 к 100%, как сделать чтобы при повторном нажатии на кнопку меню цвет не резко переключался на основной, а так же плавно переходил?

```
@keyframes opasit {
0% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.body {
background-color: aquamarine;
}

.body.active {
background: #000000;
opacity: 0;
animation: opasit 2s forwards;
-webkit-animation: opasit 2s forwards;
-moz-animation: opasit 2s forwards;
}
```

В JS всё до элементарного просто:

```
headerButton.addEventListener('click' , function() {
headerButton.classList.toggle('active');
menuView.classList.toggle('active');
menuBackground.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Все элементы заранее переданы в переменные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```js
const headerButton = document.getElementById('headerButton');
const bodyBackground = document.querySelector('body');

headerButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  bodyBackground.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  transition: background-color .8s;
}

body.active {
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<button id="headerButton">color change</button>
```